# Custom date range inline picker

Tags: angular, inline, ngx-bootstrap, daterangepicker

Framework which I use (Angular 7) and `ngx-bootstrap ^4.0.0`

I want  to  make inline daterangepicker.

Package `ngx-bootstrap` have inline  datepicker (`bs-datepicker-inline`) and directive (`bsDaterangepicker`) for classic dialog daterangepicker.

I try use attribute `container` for  create daterangepicker in element wth relative position, but after select date is component closed. When i use hide event call method show, it's working but with 'blink'.

Do you have any experience with it?

[Here is example.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-datepicker-yvctvr?file=app/app.component.html)

Comment: Would you mind rephrasing the question? It's not really clear what you're asking or trying to achieve here.

Comment: I  edit the question with some example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is something that they actually have it in their documentation [here](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/examples#range).

You can check [this Sample StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-datepicker-yvctvr?file=app/app.component.html) out for the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `bsDatepicker` from `ngx-bootstrap` like as shown below

```
<input type="text"
            class="form-control"
            [minDate]="minDate"
            [maxDate]="maxDate"
            #dp="bsDatepicker"
            bsDatepicker [(bsValue)]="myDateValue">
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-datepicker-n84b9y?file=app/app.component.html)**

Comment: know, but this is only datepicker and i  want daterangepicker which will be inline element (still showed). - see example  from question. Thanks